# how to redirect to jsp page using requestDispatcher?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I want to redirect JSP page from one servlet. All JSP pages are under **WebContent/resources/jsp/en/** and all css, js, images are under **webcontent/resources/**I have a problem of calling that JSP pages. I got **404 errors**

I can access css js and images using

```
 <%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/styles.css
```

but not jsp pages....what I am doing is

servlet:

```
String url = request.getServletPath();

if (url.equals("contactUs")) {

    System.out.println(request.getContextPath()+"..............");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/resources/jsp/en/contactUs.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

web.xml:

```
<url-pattern>/portal/*</url-pattern>
```

this is not working ...

Comment: Change the path and try again.

Comment: @jani, what should be the path?

Answer (score 2):

Concat `request.getContextPath()` with `/resources/jsp/en/contactUs.jsp`.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/resources/jsp/en/contactUs.jsp")
.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: if you are using eclipse right click on `contactUs.jsp` get qualified path and the please post here.

Comment: see all pages are under resources so I think I'm making a mistake in web.xml.....please tell me the best way to have access to all css js and jsp page with one url pattern